# A HTML page is downloaded instead of a ZIP file

Tags: c#, webclient

How to download one of zip files, listed at http://www.tneu.edu.ua/study/timetable/ using C#?

I've tried

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.tneu.edu.ua/engine/download.php?id=801", "local.zip");
```

But after execution of the DownloadFile() method, the "local.zip" receives a HTML page instead of the actual zip file.

The zip file can be downloaded readily when mouse-clicking on appropriate link in browser.
But when I copy and paste a link url "http://www.tneu.edu.ua/engine/download.php?id=801" to a browser, it redirects me to the root page as well.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does that:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate,sdch");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.tneu.edu.ua/study/timetable/");
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.tneu.edu.ua/engine/download.php?id=801", "local.zip");
```

Apparently the site want you to download only from that specific page so you need to request it as if you were referred from there.

Comment: Yeah but mistaken in paste, one second i'll fix.